# Effect "Label.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth" has no effect while other effects work

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've tried the Xamarin effects mentioned in this article:

https://smstuebe.de/2016/08/29/underlinedlabel.xamarin.forms/

(Which derived from [this](https://github.com/smstuebe/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/xamarin-forms-underline) stackoverflow question).

It works perfectly fine.

However, when I instead try to apply the label effect "AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth", it just doesn't work.

For testing this, I've set the font size in the same sample code to 300, and I changed these lines

```
            var label = (UILabel)Control;
            var text = (NSMutableAttributedString)label.AttributedText;
            var range = new NSRange(0, text.Length);
```

to these lines:

```
            var label = (UILabel)Control;
            var text = (NSMutableAttributedString)label.AttributedText;
            var range = new NSRange(0, text.Length);
            label.Lines = 1;
            label.MinimumFontSize = 6;
            label.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
```

I've tested it with iPhone iPhone 6 iOS 11.1 and iPhone X iOS 11.1 in the simulator.

Is there something special about this property which makes it un-usable for Xamarin effects or is it possible that this effect works only on a real device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you are setting a line truncation on the `Label` otherwise the normal iOS `LabelRenderer` is going to set the `Lines` property to `0` (i.e. unlimited multi-line) and thus there is nothing to resize as the entire control to sized to the text size. Also you can not set the `Lines` via an Effect as the routing effect happens before the renderer sets its properties and it gets reset to 0;

Set the LineBreakMode property:

```
<Label Text="Welcome to SizeToFitEffects, SizeToFitEffects, SizeToFitEffects, SizeToFitEffects"
    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation">
    <Label.Effects>
        <sushi:LabelSizeToFitEffect />
    </Label.Effects>
</Label>
```

In the effect, it is wise to set the `MinimumScaleFactor` to something reasonable otherwise you can end up with a font so small it is unreadable.

```
public class LabelSizeToFitEffect : PlatformEffect
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        SetSizeToFit(true);
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {
        SetSizeToFit(false);
    }

    void SetSizeToFit(bool sizeToFit)
    {
        var label = Control as UILabel;
        label.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = sizeToFit;
        label.MinimumScaleFactor = 0.33f;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How do you know that?

Comment: @tmighty Way to many years(!) of having to custom Forms  I tend to stay native now....

Comment: But you do use Xamarin.Forms and its controls + effects, right?

Comment: @tmighty I do for a couple of clients sometimes, but 95% of the Xamarin clients I work for go native only now.

Comment: Can you explain that? You use Xamarin, but you use SharedCode, or how do you do it?

Comment: @tmighty But native I mean no `Xamarin.Forms`, using strictly native Android layouts and the iOS constraint system against the native controls but using shared libraries for app/business/workflow/SQLite/Realm logic (mainly in Viper instead of MVVM).

Comment: @tmighty  I do Forms for a couple of clients sometimes, but 90% of the Xamarin clients I work for go native only now, but I have one client that has a Fody-based system that converts Forms to native (including layouts and constraints) at compile time and another that maintains their own Forms branch (including CI/UITest servers) that includes "hundreds" and "hundreds" of custom renderers, optimizations, bug fixes, etc... Knowing the native side of things makes the Forms side really easy, like your question here.

Comment: @tmighty I saw a message on my phone (from the SO app), but looks like you deleted it, assuming you fixed the problem you were having?